# Help identifying unusual Technic part, long beam with 4 studs on end

Tags: part-identification

I have a large collection of parts and I came across this slightly chewed, possibly Technic, part. No numbers on it, just the Lego on the studs. It's 15 Technic holes and then a T-piece on the end with 2 studs either side. The head seems to have a slot through it. Any ideas?

[image: Part]

[image: Part]

[image: Part]

Comment: It looks like your questions was answered. Don't forget to mark the best answer if you feel it is correct.

Answer (score 9):

That’s a [crane-arm centre](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2351#T=C). It’s usually used in non-Technic sets together with the [crane-arm outside](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2350b) to obtain a telescopic arm, e.g., for cranes or firefighter ladder trucks. The slit at the end is to insert a piece of string for using it as a cable crane.

Here's a picture showing this piece in use as the boom of a crane from 4552:

[image: 4552]

Comment: Great! Thanks very much. I shall see if I have the rest of it lurking in my pile of bits